# Binary search last element search

Tags: c

I was learning about the binary search and when I searched for the last element in the array, the search was completed in one iteration in a while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

void binSearch(int arr[], int element, int size) {
    int low = 0, mid, high = size - 1, i = 0;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == element) {
            printf("The element was found after : %d", i);
            // return mid;
        }
        if (arr[mid] < element) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[20] = { 10, 22, 28, 33, 78, 124, 410, 511, 512, 999 };
    int element = 999, size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    binSearch(arr, element, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Print out the value of `size` in `main`. Is it what you expected?

Comment: i wanted to check how many times the loop is being executed, so I added a int i and kept incrementing it.

Answer (score 1):

The definition `int arr[20] = { 10, 22, 28, 33, 78, 124, 410, 511, 512, 999 };` defines an array `arr` with a length of 20 elements, only 10 of which are initialized. The remaining elements are set to `0`, which means the array is **not** sorted.

When calling `binSearch(arr, 999, 20);` the first element tested in the loop is at `mid = 19 / 2`, and `arr[9]` is indeed `999` so `the element was found after : 0` iterations.

Your expression to compute the length of the array is correct, although `int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` would be more reliable as it does not depend on the element type of `arr`.  You should just let the compiler determine the actual length by defining `arr` as:

```
int arr[] = { 10, 22, 28, 33, 78, 124, 410, 511, 512, 999 };
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binSearch(int arr[], int element, int size) {
    int low = 0, mid, high = size - 1, i = 0;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == element) {
            printf("The element was found after : %d\n", i);
            return mid;
        }
        if (arr[mid] < element) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 10, 22, 28, 33, 78, 124, 410, 511, 512, 999 };
    int element = 999, size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    binSearch(arr, element, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code. You pass only **ten** elements, but say you will pass twenty. `sizeof()` in this case tells 20, not 10.

So the first element checked is the tenth, which by accident is exactly the one you search (999).

Try with:

```
int arr[] = {...}; // The number of elements is auto-calculated
```